# start process (as root) upon user login

Tags: process, login, root

I would like to start a process as root upon each user login. The motivation beside this is, that the process will work on encrypted home folder of particular user folder.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Then shouldn't this be the user's own process?

Answer (score 3):

If your system uses [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) (most do), you can use the [`pam_exec`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html) module in the `session` stack. Note that the user won't be logged in until the command finishes; if you want to run something in the background, fork it. Several [environment variables](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/mwg-expected-by-module-item.html#mwg-pam_get_item-description) provide information about the session. For example:

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/sbin/my-login-process
```

where `/usr/local/sbin/my-login-process` contains something like

```
#!/bin/sh
{
  exec 2>&1 >>"/var/log/my-root-service/$PAM_USER.log"
  echo "$PAM_USER logged in on $PAM_TTY on $PAM_RHOST at $(date)"
  do-something
} &
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `/etc/sudoers` file (shortcut visudo) add these lines:

```
Cmnd_Alias   CMDNAME = /path/to/binaryOrscriptToBeRunAsRoot
%groupnamehere ALL=NOPASSWD: CMDNAME
```

Instead of using a username only, creating a CMDNAME group and all users in that group have that permission:

```
groupadd groupnamehere
usermod -G groupnamehere usertoaddtogrouphere
```

To test this, become the user, and execute the command:

1. Become the user =>  su - usernamehere
2. Check groups user is in => groups
3. Run command => sudo CMDNAME restart
4. In case it isn't a global command run => sudo /path/to/binaryOrScript arg

---

An example of this is:

**/etc/sudoers**

```
Cmnd_Alias   TESTME = /usr/local/bin/testme.sh
%cmdgroup ALL=NOPASSWD: TESTME
```

**/usr/local/bin/testme.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
#netstat can only be run by root on my servers.
#File permissions are 'chmod 700'
netstat -tln |grep :80
```

**/etc/profile**

```
# You need to change 'testme' in the boundry to match the groupname created
# This checks to see if the user who just logged is part of that cmdgroup, 
# if so, it runs whatever is inside.
username=`id -un`
if groups $username | grep &>/dev/null '\btestme\b'; then
        sudo /usr/local/bin/testme.sh
fi
```

Login to a user of that group and see:

```
[nonrootuser ~]#
tcp   0  0 :::80          :::*           LISTEN
```